# Avoiding magic string for property when creating computed observable using defineProperty

Tags: typescript, durandal

Enjoying the fact that my public properties are now observable by default.   I see from the docs that you create a computed using

```
observable.defineProperty(viewModel, 'fullName', function(){
  return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
});
```

To do this in typescript (correct me if there is a better way Rob), I go:

```
import obs = require('plugins/observable'); 

class Upload {

public enableUpload: boolean = false;


constructor() {
    obs.defineProperty(this, 'enableUpload', {
        read: () => {
            var result = this.fileExists && this.createAs;
            return result;
        }
    });
}
```

The only thing I don't like is the fact that the property is passed to the defineProperty function as a string.  Any way around that?

Cheers

Jeremy

Answer (score 1):

I think you use the Durandal API?

The [documentation](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/api#module/observable/method/defineProperty) says the property name is a string.

> observable.defineProperty
>
> Defines a computed property using ES5 getters and setters. Parameters
>
> - obj : Object The target object on which to create the property.
> - **propertyName : String**
>     The name of the property to define.
> - evaluatorOrOptions : Function|object
>     The Knockout computed function or computed options object.
>
> Returns KnockoutObservable : The underlying computed observable.

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer (thanks to Rob Eisenberg):

As of v2.1, the Durandal observable plugin will wrap getters.  So instead of the above code I can get the full benefit of typescript using

```
get enableUpload(): boolean {
    return this.fileExists && this.createAs != null;;
}
```

and Durandal makes it a computed observable.